# How to Implement react-table without typescript?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

How can I re-implement `react-table` (version 8) without using `TypeScript`? I want to add some tables to the `React` project using `react-table`. When I looked at the documentation (v8), I saw that all examples are implemented with `TypeScript`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the official rep of [react-table  v8](https://github.com/tanstack/table#notable-changes) it is Full rewrite to `TypeScript` . but you can  implement this latest version of react-table without TypeScript , just convert your code from typescript to javascript

**Example**  : this Is a basic react table written in the documentation of react table with TypeScript  and   converted to javascript  :

**Index.js**  :

```
import * as React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import './index.css'

import {
  createColumnHelper,
  flexRender,
  getCoreRowModel,
  useReactTable,
} from '@tanstack/react-table'



const defaultData  = [
  {
    firstName: 'tanner',
    lastName: 'linsley',
    age: 24,
    visits: 100,
    status: 'In Relationship',
    progress: 50,
  },
  {
    firstName: 'tandy',
    lastName: 'miller',
    age: 40,
    visits: 40,
    status: 'Single',
    progress: 80,
  },
  {
    firstName: 'joe',
    lastName: 'dirte',
    age: 45,
    visits: 20,
    status: 'Complicated',
    progress: 10,
  },
]

const columnHelper = createColumnHelper()

const columns = [
  columnHelper.accessor('firstName', {
    cell: info => info.getValue(),
    footer: info => info.column.id,
  }),
  columnHelper.accessor(row => row.lastName, {
    id: 'lastName',
    cell: info => <i>{info.getValue()}</i>,
    header: () => <span>Last Name</span>,
    footer: info => info.column.id,
  }),
  columnHelper.accessor('age', {
    header: () => 'Age',
    cell: info => info.renderValue(),
    footer: info => info.column.id,
  }),
  columnHelper.accessor('visits', {
    header: () => <span>Visits</span>,
    footer: info => info.column.id,
  }),
  columnHelper.accessor('status', {
    header: 'Status',
    footer: info => info.column.id,
  }),
  columnHelper.accessor('progress', {
    header: 'Profile Progress',
    footer: info => info.column.id,
  }),
]

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(() => [...defaultData])
  const rerender = React.useReducer(() => ({}), {})[1]

  const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
  })

  return (
    <div className="p-2">
      <table>
        <thead>
          {table.getHeaderGroups().map(headerGroup => (
            <tr key={headerGroup.id}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map(header => (
                <th key={header.id}>
                  {header.isPlaceholder
                    ? null
                    : flexRender(
                        header.column.columnDef.header,
                        header.getContext()
                      )}
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {table.getRowModel().rows.map(row => (
            <tr key={row.id}>
              {row.getVisibleCells().map(cell => (
                <td key={cell.id}>
                  {flexRender(cell.column.columnDef.cell, cell.getContext())}
                </td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          {table.getFooterGroups().map(footerGroup => (
            <tr key={footerGroup.id}>
              {footerGroup.headers.map(header => (
                <th key={header.id}>
                  {header.isPlaceholder
                    ? null
                    : flexRender(
                        header.column.columnDef.footer,
                        header.getContext()
                      )}
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tfoot>
      </table>
      <div className="h-4" />
      <button onClick={() => rerender()} className="border p-2">
        Rerender
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(
  
    <App/>
,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: cool what is all that footer id stuff?

Answer (score -2):

basically react table is just a utility based table libreay which means it does not provide any styles.

Here is an example for react table

```
import React from "react"
import makeData from "./makeDats" // some dummy data
import { useTable } from 'react-table'

function TableComponent (){
 const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: 'Name',
        columns: [
          {
            Header: 'First Name',
            accessor: 'firstName',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Last Name',
            accessor: 'lastName',
          },

            ],
          },
          {
            Header: 'Info',
            columns: [
              {
                Header: 'Age',
                accessor: 'age',
              },
              {
                Header: 'Visits',
                accessor: 'visits',
              },
              {
                Header: 'Status',
                accessor: 'status',
              },
              {
                Header: 'Profile Progress',
                accessor: 'progress',
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
        []
      )
    
      const data = React.useMemo(() => makeData(20), [])
      const {
        getTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups,
        rows,
        prepareRow,
      } = useTable({
        columns,
        data,
      })
    
      // Render the UI for your table
      return (
        <table {...getTableProps()}>
          <thead>
            {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
              <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                  <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
                ))}
              </tr>
            ))}
          </thead>
          <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
            {rows.map((row, i) => {
              prepareRow(row)
              return (
                <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                  {row.cells.map(cell => {
                    return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                  })}
                </tr>
              )
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      )
    }
```

Comment: I found many of those examples, but I think they are from previous versions because no such things are mentioned in the documentation. I want something up-to-date from the latest version.